# GZip a string for output from Coldfusion results in "Content Encoding Error" in browsers

Tags: java, coldfusion, gzip

I am trying to GZip content in a variable to output to the browser.  To start I am making this very simple and not worrying about browsers that do not support gzip.  Also I have put this together from researching several methods that I could find on the web.  Some of them from people that may be reading this question.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="toGZIP"><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Fear my test</h1></body></html></cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>
ioOutput = CreateObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
gzOutput = CreateObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream");

ioOutput.init();
gzOutput.init(ioOutput);

gzOutput.write(toGZIP.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, Len(toGZIP.getBytes()));

gzOutput.finish();
gzOutput.close();
ioOutput.flush();
ioOutput.close();

toOutput=ioOutput.toString("UTF-8");
</cfscript>

<cfcontent reset="yes" /><cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip"><cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#ArrayLen( toOuptut.getBytes() )#" ><cfoutput>#toOuptut#</cfoutput><cfabort />
```

But I get an error in Firefox (and chrome and Safari)

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Anybody have any ideas?

OS: Mac OX-X Snow Leopard
CF: 9-Dev
Webserver: Apache

---

**SOLUTION**

```
<cfsavecontent variable="toGZIP"><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Fear my test</h1></body></html></cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>
ioOutput = CreateObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
gzOutput = CreateObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream");

ioOutput.init();
gzOutput.init(ioOutput);

gzOutput.write(toGZIP.getBytes(), 0, Len(toGZIP.getBytes()));

gzOutput.finish();
gzOutput.close();
ioOutput.flush();
ioOutput.close();

toOutput=ioOutput.toByteArray();
</cfscript>

<cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip"><cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#ArrayLen(toOutput)#" ><cfcontent reset="yes" variable="#toOutput#" /><cfabort />
```

Comment: @tyler-- are you still using this return and are you seeing good results from managing the gzip process internally? i want to try to do this myself as well.
i cannot get IIS 7.0 to gzip dynamic content (.cfm) pages all though it claims in can. have you ever tried to get IIS to do this?

Comment: I have not tried to get IIS to gzip dynamic pages, though I don't think I would want to as that would produce a tremendous per request overhead.  Managing the gzipped content works.  I have not had the opportunity to thoroughly test it's limits yet, but I hope to soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The follow line look completely wrong:

```
toOutput=ioOutput.toString("UTF-8");
```

You encode the GZip stream with UTF8. The result are garbage data. The best you set the GZip data as binary if ColdFusion has the option. If you can only set a string then you need an encoding that not change any bytes. For example iso1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  What do you suggest?  I think you may be right, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Ahha, I figured it out, you are right.  I removed the toString and just outputed it as binary, then used the cfcontent tag's variable attribute to send the binary to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're doing it manually over letting the web server (IIS or Apache) handle this? Both of them support GZip encoding, and will *probably* do so faster and better than your manual process.

- [Enabling GZip in IIS6](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html)
- [Enabling GZip in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)
- [Enabling GZip in Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Comment: I was going to be doing my own caching in gzip since IIS does not cache dynamically generated content.  I was going to have IIS just gzip the static cachable content.

Comment: You can cache the gzip'd data in ehcache. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have syntax error in the code: `toOuptut` instead of `toOutput`.

Unfortunately, I'm not a Java expert and can't say what exactly is wrong. But when I try to save the contents into the file using wget, it contains not zipped binary, but source HTML. It can mean that gzOutput-related processing does not produce correct output.

BTW, verifying the browser support of GZip is pretty simple. You can check the `Accept-Encoding` header, like this:

```
<cfif FindNoCase("gzip", cgi.HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING)>
    <!--- prepare the gzipped text --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yeah, the toOuptut was a copy paste issue because I was condensing the code into something that would look better here, oops.