# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - How to configure gzip compression support?

Tags: http, compression, gzip, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We are developing a hybrid mobile app using Worklight version 5.0.6.1.

I'd like to know how to apply gzip compression to improve performance by reducing the size of the content during data transmission.

I searched the infocenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html and stackoverflow a well as in Google, but could not  find a solution.

Below is the outline of the architecture:

```
Mobile devices <=> Big IP <=> IIS 6 <=> WAS 8/Worklight 5.0.6
```

So my questions are:

1. I'm not quite sure whether I should need to setup gzip on either IIS or WAS or Worklight or all?
2. What about the WebSphere plugin config file plugin-cfg.xml? Do I need to configure anything in it to enable gzip?

I did find information on setting http compression on IIS6 below:

[enable GZIP compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949853/enable-gzip-compression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight 5.0.6 does not support GZIP compression. You can upgrade to Worklight 6.0 or higher where the app can request the Worklight server to [send compressed data](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) using the `compressResponse` option when making an `invokeProcedure` call . You have to enable compression in only IIS or Worklight not in both.