# how can I gzip compress static files in asp.net without changing iis 6 manager settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gzip, yslow

when I Use Yslow tool in my page it shows me `Grade C On compress components with gzip`

[image: Grade C]

I have tried to find solutions online, But most of the results returned were either for IIS 7 or above version, or they said to change settings in IIS manager...
I cant change settings in IIS Manager, So is there any other way through which i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft page looks like the right place for an explanation of configuring IIS 6.0: [Using HTTP Compression for Faster Downloads (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true)

Source: SO question "[enable GZIP compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949853/enable-gzip-compression)"