# Static content not gzipped to IE9 from IIS7

Tags: iis-7, internet-explorer-9, gzip

I've enabled gzip compression in IIS using the config settings specified [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444505/361684).

When I request a text file using Firefox, I can see in Firebug that the response is gzipped:

[image: Firebug gzip request/response headers]

But when I request the same text file using IE9, the dev tools show it is *not* gzipped:

[image: IE Dev tools gzip request headers]
[image: IE Dev tools gzip response headers]

Why is IIS not sending the txt file compressed?  Am I missing some IIS setting?  Is my browser misconfigured?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi - Thanks.  Yes, fiddler does show that it is indeed compressed.  That's obnoxious that IE dev tools don't show all of the response headers.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd compare both requests using Fiddler since IE dev tools doesn't seem to be showing all response headers