# Adding various filetypes to my IIS7 GZip compression

Tags: iis-7, compression, gzip

I have enabled GZip compression via web.config with many helps from another question: [Enable IIS7 gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)

I have tested the compression with Live HTTP Headers plugin in FF, and it correctly shows

> Content-Encoding: gzip

I have added the following code to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

But is it correct that this code only compress the javascripts and not the CSS, Images and ASP documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I'm just not that bright... It does zip everything after all ;)