# How to make static Html page go through HttpModule in IIS7.0?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, static-html

I have created a simple HttpModule which removes whitespaces from response before sending it to the client. This works fine for an aspx page on IIS7.0 but if i create a static html page and call it, the HttpModule does not kick in (the way i know is because the source contains whitespaces, which otherwise should have been removed). Apparently there is something i m not doing right, but dont know what.

My website is in an Application Pool with .NET 4.0 and `ManagedPipelineMode = Integrated`.

I have added my module as a ManagedModule and refers to an strong-name-key assembly from GAC.

thanks

Edit- here is the system.webserver part from web.config

```xml
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="RemoveWhitespaceHttpModule" 
         type="HttpModules.Modules.RemoveWhitespaceHttpModule, HttpModules, 
           Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8a83u4bi47o9fo0d" 
           preCondition="" />
  </modules>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <add value="TestForm.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Edit- Fixed it. For anyone interested, this is how my module checks the response and then decides whether to proceed with whitespace removal or not

```
if (contentType.Equals("text/html") 
  && httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 200 
  && httpContext.CurrentHandler != null)
{ ... }
```

The problem was with the third condition above **httpContext.CurrentHandler != null**. when calling this module for static .html pages, the currentHandler was null and hence the code never went inside to manipulate html. i have removed this third condition and it works now. thanks for your answers everyone

Comment: rename your static .html page to .aspx (no change in content needed) and the thing should work

Comment: GZIP already does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip

Comment: @alex - thats not what i want to achieve. i could have easily done that and not raised this question at all. i want to be able to use this httpmodule for not only asp.net applications, but cold fusion ones as well. my aim is to get it working for .html pages and take it from there.

Comment: @jrummell - thanks, for that. but that does not really answer my question :) i dont want to enable gzip ('cause the load balancer that we use wont support it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, in the web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

This is a quick and easy solution, but can cause issues / performance issues.

Comment: Do you have your module registered in system.webserver > modules? otherwise it won't get picked up. and if so, please post your web.config portion

Comment: yes.. added the system.webserver part from my web.config in the main question

Comment: Your web.config looks fine, except that runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" is superfluous in your case as it just runs all modules as preCondition="", which you already have. Can you debug your module to make sure it's getting hit?

Comment: yours have been the most helpful answers, but sadly i cant upvote you (i dont have enough points to do that). thanks for you help anyways

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the Handler Mapping in your IIS.

How a handler works is that on IIS, the handler is registered and supposed to handle a particuler type of page. You can look at the "Handler Mappings" in the IIS [In the run command type `inetmgr` and hit enter. IIS Manager will pop up and look for Handler Mappings in the IIS section.]

Comment: what specifically would you advice me to configure. i have already tried adding a handler mapping, with *.html but this did not serve any purpose

Comment: He asked about HttpModule, not HttpHandler