# How to Use GZIP files In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, gzip

I want to use GZIP files to reduce the page load time.
I have Converted All my JS files in GZIP files.

Now I want to know How Do I set IIS (I am using IIS 7) that this can be work.

Second thing How do i call GZIP file in My Asp.net Pages as well?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to serve up GZIP files or JS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have Converted All my JS files in GZIP files.

Not necessary. Just enable GZIP compression in IIS settings. [This article](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-enable-gzip-on-iis7/) gives details on how to do so. [This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip) talks about how to validate that the settings were successfully applied.

> Second thing How do i call GZIP file in My Asp.net Pages as well

Compression can be enabled for static and/or dynamic files. ASPX pages are considered a dynamic type; enabling dynamic content compression will cause them to be GZIP'd before they are served to a compatible user agent.

To validate, you can use a tool like http://gtmetrix.com/ which will warn about uncompressed resources.