# How to send compressed data in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, java-me

I have created an ASP.net application with several aspx. Some of them are used like an API link. These API pages are consumed by J2ME application which passes some headers. I am checking these headers specifically "Accept-Encoding" so that my page could send compressed contents.

The following code shows a sample code from one of those API pages.

```
byte[] buffer;
    int bufferLength;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bufferLength = Request.ContentLength;
        buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        buffer = Request.BinaryRead(bufferLength);
        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        bool needEncrypted = (Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] != null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CRequestQuestParameter QuestPara = ser.Deserialize<CRequestQuestParameter>(s);
            CUtil utilFun = new CUtil(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheConnectionString"].ToString());

            CResponseQuestionSets res = new CResponseQuestionSets();


            //No error setting
            res.ErrorCode = -1;
            res.ErrorMessage = "";
            res.IsError = false;

            //Return data
            res.ResponseData = utilFun.GetQuestionSet(QuestPara);
            if (res.ResponseData != null) {
                res.ErrorCode = -1;
                res.ErrorMessage = "";
                res.IsError = false;

            }
            else
            {
                res.ErrorCode = 102;
                res.ErrorMessage = "User does not exists";
                res.IsError = true;

            }



            if (needEncrypted)
            {
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            }

            Response.ContentType = "application/json charset=utf-8";
            Response.Write(ser.Serialize(res));
            Response.End();

        }
    }
```

The problem here is that the J2ME application is not receiving the data as compressed but does gets the header "Content-Encoding".

Can anybody help me out solve this issue?

Comment: maybe if you move the filter on the start of this call, I mean on page init.

Comment: @Aristos: OK, will check for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do GZIP encoding in your code.

This is fully handled by configuring your site properly in both [IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true) and [IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip).