# Can I send zipped up files to the broswer using Yahoo Compressor?

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I'm using Yahoo's Minifier here:

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

I use it to compress CSS and Javascript.  It also has the option to zip/encode the data.

The .css version looks like this - ArcC.min.css.gz

The .js version looks like this - ArcJ.min.js.gz

Can I plug this in to my HTML directly like this, after I upload the files to my server?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ArcC.min.css.gz"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ArcJ.min.js.gz"></script>
```

Comment: Just tested...that breaks my page....O.K...so I how do I use these zipped files then?

Comment: You don't directly serve up gzipped files for use like that. You put in normal uncompressed files, and configure the webserver to gzip them on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/weblog/web-development/css/the-definitive-css-gzip-method) on gziping CSS.  As mentioned in the article, the best solution  is to have your server gzip all outgoing files.

Here's the relevant code from that page.

```
<?php 
ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 60 * 60 ;
$ExpStr = "Expires: " . 
gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",
time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
php_value auto_prepend_file gzip-css.php
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't support gzipped files.  It's best to let the server do the compression.  Your server should be able to decide whether to send a gzipped version or an uncompressed version, based on the `Accept-Encoding` header the browser submitted with the request.

How to set up your server for gzip:

**IIS:** [Answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444505/361684)
**Apache:** [mod_deflate documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)