# GZIP compression works on local host but doesn't work on IIS 7.5 host

Tags: asp.net, compression, iis-7.5, gzip

I want to use GZIP compression on my website contents ... and I've place my code into `PreRequestHandlerExecute` in global.asax.cs file.
It works on my local host (IIS , ASP.NET ) but when I upload it to remote host (which I haven't access to it's config. files) and when I look at fiddler results there is no compression at all. Here is an example of request and response:

Request Header:

```
GET **********/script/iscroll.js HTTP/1.1  
Host: *****  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1  
Accept: */*  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Connection: keep-alive  
Referer: ********************  
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0w3uurg51f2mfdjhexzoegvq`
```

Respone Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Content-Type: application/x-javascript  
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Sep 2012 06:18:19 GMT  
Accept-Ranges: bytes  
ETag: "46857abaf796cd1:0"  
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin  
Date: Fri, 21 Sep 2012 20:46:00 GMT  
Content-Length: 34777
```

Comment: This might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)

Comment: Not working for me either. Works great in Webmatrix but not IIS 7.5 on Server 2008r2. Did you ever find a solution?