# Compression of bundles created by asp.net bundling using 'System.Web.Optimization'?

Tags: asp.net, gzip, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization, system.web.optimization

I have created bundles in my asp.net web solution by using the new bundling and minification package by MS. Everything is properly bundled and minified (used global.asax way) but when I deploy on IIS the bundle is not getting compressed (gzip) , I don't want to enable dynamic compression (as it will compress all dynamic content), just want to compress bundles only.

What to do ?

What is the mime type of a bundled output, like for this bundle named 'Jquery' here :

```
"http://Myhost/MySite/JQuery?v=1Oof3SDB0npBNcnfiEpdM9WovwwmP-UGKz3QrSQLPPQ1"
```

So I can add the same in webconfig file in httpCompression section for gzip compression.

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: Are you publishing in release mode and do you have debug="false" in your Config?

Comment: That is not a problem , minification and bundling happens properly in release mode and vice versa. I am concerned about g-zipping the bundled content

Comment: See if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enabled dynamic compression in IIS7, there is not other way to compress bundles like this other than enabling dynamic compression, although it is advised that you implement this only if you are using IIS7 or above, dynamic compression in lower versions is not optimized and will tax your server.

Running my solution on production after implementing this without any issues.

Comment: The problem with dynamic compression is it won't cache the compressed content on the server like static compression will.  Is there any way around this?