# How to compress json response in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nancy

Currently, I'm converting datatable to json, it's working fine.

The problem is I want to compress the response. Anyone suggest me. WSID...
I want something like that :- https://gist.github.com/chrisnicola/1147568

```
            using (PooledConnection pooledConnection = AdomdConnectionPool.GetConnection(connstring))
            {
                // Execute the query
                AdomdDataAdapter adapter = new AdomdDataAdapter(q, pooledConnection.Connection);
                DataTable x = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(x);

                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                List<object> header = new List<object>();
                List<List<object>> rows = new List<List<object>>();

                foreach (DataColumn col in x.Columns)
                {
                    header.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim());
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in x.Rows)
                {
                    List<object> rowtemp = new List<object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in x.Columns)
                    {
                        rowtemp.Add(row[col]); //For Row 24012014----- Rohit
                    }
                    rows.Add(rowtemp);
                }
                return Response.AsJson(new { header, rows });

            }
```

Comment: Is the call to a webserice / webapi / mvc call? If this is the case it should be possible to add some config, or add gzip to header call

Comment: you can enable compression at iis level see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186233/Utilize-gzip-compression-in-IIS    Is this also a solution for you

Answer (score 1):

If you want this done within your Nancy code (as opposed to e.g. IIS configuration) you can create your own custom serializer/deserializer and let Nancy pick it up.
see Phillip Haydons blog for information on doing this: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/05/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Why not serialize the initial object (that is large), compress the serialized object, send the  compressed string.

You already have the json? Compress it using built in compression routines in .net4.5, and send the compressed string.

On the other side, reverse the process.

I am doing this in one of my projects with normal WCF.

This all assuming you have control over client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on dynamic compression in IIS (despite the warning) is the right thing to do.

[Enable IIS7 gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)

These are old posts, but still relevant:

["Turning on Compression is a VERY low effort and VERY high reward thing to do"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)

and

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/reducing-your-websites-bandwidth-usage.html