# ASP.net Custom Http Modules - IhttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gzip, httpmodule

Running IIS 7

I'm trying to implement a custom Http Module, what I actually want is to implement gzip compression.

There seems to be a few ways to do this.

I am trying to do this by accessing the HttpApplication.BeginRequest event and add some code there that will use gzip.

I am using umbraco so I don't have a global.asax file so what I have got is a class file inside the app code folder of my website:

```
public class GzipHttpCompressionModule : IHttpModule
{
public GzipHttpCompressionModule()
{}

public void Dispose()
{}

public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest +=
        (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));

}

private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
}
```

}

Then inside my web-config file I register the module

```
<httpModules>
..
<!-- Register Custom Http Gzip Module   -->
<add name="GzipHttpCompressionModule" type="GzipHttpCompressionModule"/>
..
</httpModules>
```

When I put a break point in Application_BeginRequest it never gets hit when I browse the website

[Enable IIS7 gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip)  << The forth Answer down is the technique I am trying to implement.

Any ideas? why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

The `<httpModules>` tag inside the `<system.web>` tag is only used by old IIS versions (<=6) or when you use the classic mode (not recommended). Use `<modules>` in `<system.webServer>` instead.

More information here: http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2010/09/16/HttpModule-Not-Working-In-IIS7.aspx