# WCF compressing JSON response

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF web service based on JSON and POST method which have a function called website returning a JSON with more 2KB content. This service has more than 10K requests per second. So, I have lots of textual data to be passed via network and I/O. I think I can reduce this volume of data by compressing the response automatically. I know that by setting a header in client side for accepting zipped content, the client  can notify the server that compressed content is acceptable. But how the server can send compressed content?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/how-to-get-gzip-compression-working-in-wcf-4-5) link, and implement it. But it works only for SOAP which is xml-based, not JSON. I mean that this configuration:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="BinaryCompressionBinding"> 
    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/> 
    <httpTransport /> 
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

can not work with JSON because we have to use `binaryMessageEncoding`, where as JSON needs `webMessageEncoding` and it does not support `compressionFormat`.

Also, IIS dynamic compression can not help me too. I have added markup it needs to compress JSON.

---

**Update:**
This is my applicationhost.config:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="0"> <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" /> <dynamicTypes> <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" /> <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" /> </dynamicTypes> </httpCompression>
```

Comment: What do you mean by added markup and why dynamic compression isn't helping you?

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou by markup I mean using <urlCompression> in webconfig with proper attributes such as doDynamicCompression. Also I have added <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> to applicationhost.config. I think Dynamic compression is used on web pages and the content of a POST request or response is not compressed.

Comment: does your service actually returns "application/javascript" ?? The type has to exactly match . For example for WebApi the added type has to be "application/json; charset=utf-8".

If you manage to set dynamic compression on IIS level it actualy works for json responses.

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou
The service return a JSON as a response.
Here is the header:
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1049
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 11:15:04 GMT
Yes I Also added <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />.

Comment: Then you need to add <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" /> on your applicationhost.config. Warning adding this to your web.config won't work.See-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844960/web-api-gzip-not-being-applied/40910034#40910034

Comment: I have added this too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative and more control , you can manually compress your responses with c# code within a Message Inspector.

For WebApi I did something similar using delegating handler. You can wrap my code into a **Message Inspector** for WCF i think.

[Compress WebApi Response using delegating handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815706/webapi-gzip-when-returning-httpresponsemessage/40910397#40910397)

[Message Inspectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or to use IIS level compression add

```
<add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
```

On your applicationhost.config.
[See about json compression enabled mime type here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844960/web-api-gzip-not-being-applied/40910034#40910034)

---

**Update:**
With special thanks to @AnestisKivranoglou, I have successfully implemented a gzip compression for Json responses of WCF. To make the answer of @AnestisKivranoglou more accurate, I want to add some details to his answer.

You have to change the `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply` of `Message Inspector` like bellow:

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var prop = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
                var accept = prop.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accept) && accept.Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    var item = new DoCompressExtension();
                    OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch { }

            return null;
        }


void IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            if (OperationContext.Current.Extensions.OfType<DoCompressExtension>().Count() > 0)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponseProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                httpResponseProperty.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");
                reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = httpResponseProperty;                                
            }            
        }
```

These 2 snippet of codes let you know whether the client can accept `gzip` or not! So, you implemented a `behaviorExtensions` that can capture a request before reply and after receive. Now you need to implement a `bindingElementExtensions` using [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx). Note that you have to fix the `GZip` problem using [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmetzgar/2011/03/10/compressing-messages-in-wcf-part-one-fixing-the-gzipmessageencoder-bug/). Finally it remains a small number of changes listed bellow:

1. Add an item to `ApplyConfiguration` function:

`case "webMessageEncoding":binding.innerBindingElement = new WebMessageEncodingBindingElement();break;`

2. Change custom binding from `innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding"` to `innerMessageEncoding="webMessageEncoding"`.

If nothing was missed, you can check and call the service using `Post` method and `Json` an receive compressed responses if you add `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate` to your request's header. If you dont add this header you'll receive normal responses which is not compressed.

Comment: Do I have to notify the client that the message is compressed?! And it has to decompressed it?

Comment: The CompressedContent class handles that by adding  the "Content-Encoding" header to the response if it is compressed. That is what your client needs to de-compress the response.

Comment: I think, it is not possile to use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, CompressHandler.GetSingleton());` in WCF Global.asax.cs file.

Comment: yes you will have to implement the equivalent for Message Inspectors . MessageHandlers are WebApi Specific related. Message Inspectors are for WCF

Comment: I implemented the code but I get `500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException`! I think message inspector has problem with json.