# Angular ng build --prod && gzip-all \"dist/anti-fraud/*.*\" build is working but not Gzip " 'gzib' is not recognized"

Tags: angular, optimization, .net-core, gzip

I want to optimize Angular APP with .Net Core 
I use this Command in cmd 
-> ng build --prod and it works fine to minify all Jscript files in \dist Folder

#### but i want to use gzip to compress those Jscript Files

I installed GZip-all
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-all

I use this Command 
->ng build --prod && gzip-all \"dist/anti-fraud/*.*\" 
and tried another one

```
    ng build --prod && gzip-all \"dist/*.*\"
```

but it gives this message 
"'gzip-all' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

and this happens with any package i install like tar 
->ng build --environment=prod && tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz dist/prod/* 
also with Zipper 
->ng build --prod && gzipper --verbose ./dist 
gives Message"'gzipper' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

and Not compress any file in dist folder 
any help?

Edit:
I have find the solution 
I have not installed gzip in the global so i installed it 
->npm -g i gzip-all
then

```
  ng build --prod && gzip-all dist/*.*
```

it works good :)

Comment: For the npm gzip-all package, I'd say it's normal if you haven't installed it globally. 
 Try specifying the full path of the binary instead of just it's name.Besides, why don't you let your webserver do it?

Comment: you can use --build-optimizer instead

Comment: @David Could you explain how to let webserver do it?

Comment: @AliMaleki I have tried it but it does not create .gz files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to differentiate minification and gzip compression.

Minifying/uglyfying your JS is normally done automatically with the following command

```
ng build --prod
```

unless you turned off that setting in `angular.json` file.

Then, you can ask your web server to dynamically compress these files with gzip (or other compression method) so that it takes less time to transfer over the network.

Getting this done depends on your webserver (example for for [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip), for [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/))

Comment: after installing it in global gives this message 
gzipped 0 files

Comment: thank you :)   
I have not installed gzip in the global so i installed it 
->npm -g i gzip-all
then

  ng build --prod && gzip-all dist/*.* 

it works good :)

Comment: Gettiing an error-                                                                                                      
 The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine